# Expo File System can't find or open local image

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-file-system

I'd like to convert an image stored in root/assets/images/img.png to base64, using

```
   useEffect(() => {
      const convertImageToBase64 = async () => {
        try {
          const imageUri = 'assets/images/super.jpg'; // Replace with your image path
          const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory+imageUri, {
            encoding: 'base64',
          });
          console.log(base64);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error converting image to base64:', error);
        }
      };
  
      convertImageToBase64(); // Call the conversion function when the component mounts
    }, []);
```

It says no file or directory:
Error converting image to base64: [Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.readAsStringAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/assets/images/super.jpg (No such file or directory)]

I tried this to see what directories & files it could load:

```
useEffect(() => {
      const logFolderPaths = async () => {
        try {
          // Get the document directory
          const documentDirectory = FileSystem.documentDirectory;
          console.log('Document Directory:', documentDirectory);
          await listFilesAndFolders(documentDirectory);
    
          // Get the cache directory
          const cacheDirectory = FileSystem.cacheDirectory;
          console.log('Cache Directory:', cacheDirectory);
          await listFilesAndFolders(cacheDirectory);
    
          // Get the bundled assets directory
          const bundleDirectory = FileSystem.bundleDirectory;
          console.log('Bundle Directory:', bundleDirectory);
          await listFilesAndFolders(bundleDirectory);
    
          // Get the bundled assets directory (expo updates)
          const bundledAssetsDirectory = FileSystem.bundledAssetsDirectory;
          console.log('Bundled Assets Directory:', bundledAssetsDirectory);
          await listFilesAndFolders(bundledAssetsDirectory);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching folder paths:', error);
        }
      };
    
      const listFilesAndFolders = async (directory) => {
        try {
          const result = await FileSystem.readDirectoryAsync(directory);
          console.log(`Files and folders in ${directory}:`, result);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error listing files and folders in ${directory}:`, error);
        }
      };
    
      logFolderPaths();
    }, []);
```

The document and cache directories work, but the bottom two returned this error:
LOG  Bundle Directory: asset:///
ERROR  Error listing files and folders in asset:///: [Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.readDirectoryAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsupported scheme for location 'asset:///'.]
LOG  Bundled Assets Directory: undefined
Web Bundling complete 18ms
ERROR  Error listing files and folders in undefined: [Error: Call to function 'ExponentFileSystem.readDirectoryAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Asset](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/#asset) library to handle static resources.

> An asset is any file that lives alongside the source code of your app that the app needs at runtime.

`loadAsync` downloads the asset data to a local file in the cache directory.

```
const [{ localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(require('./assets/images/super.jpg'));
```